# JavaFX2.2: Save image to file, save the path to a variable and show the image on other stage

Tags: image, save, javafx-2, bufferedimage

I am trying to make an inventory application with product pictures for each entry. I have a `filechooser` where I can select the picture and show it in a `imageviewer` field.

But I don't know:

- how I can save the picked picture in a working folder
- write the path to the picture in a variable, that I can show the picture on another window/stage (`Imageviewer`) in my application.

Here is the code of the `filechooser` and the `imageviewer` where the picture is displayed:

```
{
@FXML
private void uploadPicture() {
FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();

// Set extension filter
FileChooser.ExtensionFilter extFilterJPG = new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter(
"JPG files (*.jpg)", "*.JPG");
FileChooser.ExtensionFilter extFilterPNG = new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter(
"PNG files (*.png)", "*.PNG");
fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().addAll(extFilterJPG, extFilterPNG);

File file = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
try {
BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(file);
Image image = SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(bufferedImage, null);
productPicture.setImage(image);
} catch (IOException ex) {
Logger.getLogger(ToolEditDialogController.class.getName()).log(
Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To save (or, I guess, copy) the file to another location, just do

```
ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, format, new File(...));
```

where format is "PNG" or "JPG", and the File is a file in your working directory.

For the second part of the question, I'm not quite sure of the context. Do you want to display this image in a separate window immediately, or do you to display it at a later time in response to the user doing something?